# List of "#pragma ide diagnostic ignored" for CLion (and other IDEs?)

Tags: c++, ide, static-analysis, pragma, clion

I've been using the Google Testing framework with CLion, and the IDE can't parse a lot of the macros in the framework.  Today I clicked the light bulb next to the inspection and clicked "ignore inspection for statement" and CLion inserted

```
#pragma ide diagnostic ignored "CannotResolve"
```

along with `clang diagnostic push` and `pop` pragmas.  This seems useful, but I can't find a list of allowed values for diagnostics to ignore anywhere.  Does anyone know where I can find such a list?  Also, does anyone know if this is just a CLion thing, or is it more broadly applicable?  Is this intended to be a signal to all IDEs, even if CLion is the only one using it? (or is it the only one?)

Comment: List request are off topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: @NathanOliver this isn't a list request, it's a documentation request.  Should have phrased it differently.  The "list requests" that are off topic for Stack Overflow are things like "List of C++ IDEs" or "List of Java visualization frameworks".  This is asking about a specific feature and about where it is documented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `#pragma IDE`, but for `#pragma GCC` and `#pragma clang`, you can use any `-W` option that does not require an `=`.

For gcc you can use, `gcc --help=warnings` to list all possible warnings, though note that different warnings apply to different languages.

For clang, there is no direct way to list all the warnings, but running with `-Weverything` is a good way to find all possible warnings that apply to any given piece of code.